# Is $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x - x_0 + c)$ always?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f(x)$ be any real valued function. Is $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) =
>  \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x - x_0 + c)$ for $c, x_0 \in D $ domain of $f(x)$?

Context of question : I just wanted to ask if I am given that an additive function $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ is continuous at $x=0$ then can I use the fact that $\forall c \in R \; \; \; \lim_{x \to c}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x + c) =  \lim_{x \to 0}f(x) + \lim_{x\to 0}f(c) = f(0) + f(c) = 0 + f(c) = f(c)$, ie, prove that $f(x) $ is continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I don't understand the $c, x_0 \in D$ constraint.  I think you only need $f$ defined near $c$, $x_0$ should be arbitrary.

Comment: @Malcolm $x_0$ must lie within the domain (unless $x_0=\pm\infty$ and function is defined on the ray). What would $\lim_{x\to -1}f(x)$ mean for a function $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: @Tomasz The question asks about the behavior of $f(x-x_0+c)$ as $x \to x_0$.  In your example if $c>0$ and the domain of $f$ is $(0,\infty)$ then there is nothing wrong with asking $\lim_{x\to -1} f(x+1+c)$

Comment: Context of question : I just wanted to ask if I am given that an additive function $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ is continuous at $x=0$ then can I use the fact that $\forall c \in R \; \; \; \lim_{x \to c}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x + c) =  \lim_{x \to 0}f(x) + \lim_{x\to 0}f(c) = f(0) + f(c) = 0 + f(c) = f(c)$, ie, prove that $f(x) $ is continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @So Lo.  Yes, this works just fine although I think you mean $\ldots = f(0) + f(c) = f(0+c) = f(c)$